# Использование DayArchiveView в Django

Tags: django

#### Views

```
class ActionDayArchiveView(DayArchiveView):
    template_name = 'core/dashboard.html'
    allow_empty = True
    month_format = '%m'
    date_field = "records__created"

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Action.objects.dashboard(
            user=self.request.user
        )
        return qs
```

#### Models

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                   editable=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        abstract = True

class ActionManager(models.Manager):

    def dashboard(self, user):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(user=user)
        qs = qs.annotate(
            record_sum=Sum('records__value'))
        return qs


class Action(TimeStampedModel):
    objects = ActionManager()

    ...

class Record(TimeStampedModel):
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='records')
    ...
```

#### Ошибка:

**FieldDoesNotExist at /archive/2018/10/01/**
**Action has no field named 'records__created'**

В качестве date_field я использую records__created, связь указана в Record. В этом и проблема. Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Поле `created` должно находиться в `Record` модели, скорее всего из-за этого и ошибка. Скорее всего у Вас должно быть что-то вроде такого: `records__timestamped__created`, где `timestamped` - related name ключа на модель `TimeStampedModel`.

Comment: @floydya ошибка таже `Action has no field named 'records__timestamped__created'`. Хотя я могу обращаться так [`qs = qs.filter(records__created....`](https://github.com/andreyvpng/lifelog/blob/master/django/core/models.py#L23) и это не вызывает ошибки. Вообще реализовал, то что хотел по-другому, но теперь мне просто интересно, почему тот код не работает :)